# How to get output with println()

Tags: java

I want to write a program that it should give me `R3` as output. My code is here:

```
public class Main {
    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);

        boolean P;
        boolean Q;
        System.out.println("please enter 2 number P and Q");
        System.out.print('\n');
        P = console.nextBoolean();
        Q = console.nextBoolean();

        boolean R1;
        boolean R2;
        boolean R3;

        R1 = (P & Q);
        R2 = (Q == R1);
        R3 = (P == R2);
        System.out.print("the output is");
        System.out.println(R3);
    }
}
```

I searched a lot, but I dont know why this code doesn't work. This code run but when I enter `P` and `Q`, I can't see any output. Can you help me please?

Comment: So, what do you enter when you run the program? Tell us the sequence of keys you type on your keyboard. Also tell us why you ask the user to enter numbers, since you only read booleans.

Comment: This works if you enter `true` and `false` when prompted. It throws an exception if you enter numbers as prompted.

Comment: How are you running the program? Can't find anything wrong.

Comment: Your code also works fine for me (it prints `the output is <whatever>`).  You need to give more specific information about *exactly* what you are doing.

Comment: P and Q are 2 boolean number for example we can enter 0,0 or 0,1 or 1,0 or 1,1...and for these we should obtain 0,1,1,1 as output...I enter 0,0 but I cant see the output...it is a homework

Comment: Read https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html. Booleans are not numbers. The only values of booleans are true and false. Not 0 and 1.

Comment: Boolean is `true` or `false`. You can use integer input and then convert it using `input != 0` to achieve what you're trying.

Comment: oh,thanks...yes I think I should enter 0 or 1 as input,but now I enter true and false and it works..

Comment: How did you not get an `InputMismatchException` when you entered a `0` or `1`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use 0 and 1, here you go:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
boolean p = scanner.nextInt() != 0;
boolean q = scanner.nextInt() != 0;
boolean r1 = p && q;
boolean r2 = q == r1;
boolean r3 = p == r2;
System.out.println(r3 ? 1 : 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

The code is right and it's working for me as well.. you have to input boolean values for it to return you the answer.
If you type "true" or "false" it works fine.
You can't feed it 0s or 1s